# How do i find someone ip location and make a link when found?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want a code that will find someones ip then make a link come up for that location (Link goes to a different page with content for that location)

I found some code but i dont think its doing what i though it did? Any ideas?

```
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
    $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
    $("#address").html("Location: " + response.city + ", " + response.region);
    $("#details").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
}, "jsonp");
```

Html code:

```
<h3>Client side IP geolocation using <a href="http://ipinfo.io">ipinfo.io</a></h3>

<hr/>
<div id="ip"></div>
<div id="address"></div>
<hr/>Full response: <pre id="details"></pre>
```

Comment: Same origin policy, your need to use PHP to proxy the json into your jquery.

Comment: @LozCherone it's a jsonp request, so sop doesn't apply

Comment: What does it do that you don't expect, or what does it not do that you do expect? Do you see any errors?

Comment: Your code is working fine - http://jsfiddle.net/d4rw5/

Comment: Drahcir  No, i put it on my website and look: http://onlythebestoftheweb.x10.mx/experiments/php-Location.html

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your comment I see your code is wrong, its jQuery not PHP:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
<title>
Test
</title>
<body>
<h3>Client side IP geolocation using <a href="http://ipinfo.io">ipinfo.io</a></h3>

<hr/>
<div id="ip"></div>
<div id="address"></div>
<hr/>Full response: <pre id="details"></pre>

<?php 
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
    $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
    $("#address").html("Location: " + response.city + ", " + response.region);
    $("#details").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
}, "jsonp");
?>
```

Ive put together a *friendly-api-consumer* example, that will cache the result for 60secs (really you should increase this to 86400 = 1 day to save your precious request quota), this will speed up the loading on subsequent requests & not bombard the API as stated on `http://ipinfo.io/developers`, **You are limited to 1,000 API requests per day**...

```
<?php 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset($_POST['ip'])){

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    if($_POST['ip'] == $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']){
        //fix ip6 address for testing
        $_POST['ip'] = ($_POST['ip']='::1') ? '127.0.0.1' : $_POST['ip'];

        //cache path
        $cache_folder = dirname(__FILE__) . '/cache';

        //cache file, this will store the API response for the ip
        $cache_file = $cache_folder.'/'.$_POST['ip'].'.json';

        //check folder exists
        if(!file_exists($cache_folder)){mkdir($cache_folder, 0755);}

        //do if cache files not found or older then 60 seconds (60 should suffice)
        if(!file_exists($cache_file) || filemtime($cache_file) < (time() - 60)){
            //query API, apending the users IP address to the url
            $data = file_get_contents('http://ipinfo.io/'.$_POST['ip']);

            //store for future use
            file_put_contents($cache_file, $data);
        }else{
            $data = file_get_contents($cache_file);
        }
        exit($data);
    }else{
        exit(array('access denied, missing $_POST[\'ip\']'));
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $.post("index.php", { 'ip': '<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];?>' },
        function(response) {
            $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
            $("#address").html("Location: " + response.city + ", " + response.region);
            $("#details").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Client side IP geolocation using <a href="http://ipinfo.io">ipinfo.io</a></h3>
    <hr/>
    <div id="ip"></div>
    <div id="address"></div>
    <hr/>Full response: <pre id="details"></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

You could even change it from a *dirty file cache* to a persistent cache and store the result in a database.

Hope it helps, happy coding!

Comment: Look at it now didnt do anything either but i think your on the right track. http://onlythebestoftheweb.x10.mx/experiments/php-Location.html

Comment: Change the file extension to **.php** not **.html**, that should do it ;p

Comment: yeah, though not working.. god i hate free hosting!! via FTP check that the cache folder is there, if its not create it, also if you have logs check them you might not have curl installed. Ill update with the file_get_contents() if you dont.

Comment: @user3590931 ive updated answer, with fgc if curl not installed. hopefully it that ;p

Comment: ok ive found the issue your server has curl but open_basedir, you should see `Warning: curl_setopt(): CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when an open_basedir` in your log. ive updated the answer and removed that option. **:)**